# How to find which Table is mapped by fluent API?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, fluent-interface

I need to find which table is mapped to an EntityTypeConfiguration class.
For example:

```
  public class PersonMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
    {
        public PersonMap()
        {
    ...
            this.ToTable("Persons");
    ....

        }
    }
```

I need something like reverse mapping:

```
var map=new PersonMap(); 
string table =map.GetMappedTableName();
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the field to PersonMap:

```
public class PersonMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{
    public string TableName { get { return "Persons"; } }
    public PersonMap()
    {
        ...
        this.ToTable(TableName);
        ...
    }
}
```

Access it like so:

```
var map = new PersonMap(); 
string table = map.TableName;
```

If you may not know the type of map, use an interface:

```
public interface IMap
{
    string TableName { get; }
}
public class PersonMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>, IMap
{
    public string TableName { get { return "Persons"; } }
    public PersonMap()
    {
        ...
        this.ToTable(TableName);
        ...
    }
}
```

Access like so:

```
IMap map = new PersonMap(); 
string table = map.TableName;
```

Comment: It was good idea to find TableName without going into EntityTypeConfiguration. But what about Column Names? 
For example in PersonMap:
this.ToTable(TableName);
this.Property(t => t.Code).HasColumnName("Code");
this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("FirstName");
this.Property(t => t.Family).HasColumnName("LastName");
Is there a way to get MappedColumn Name?
For example: 
PersonMap map = new PersonMap();
var pr = map.Property(p => p.Name);
string columnName = pr.HasColumnName; //expect FirstName

Comment: @Saber exactly. This isn't a scalable solution.